# Como hago para que el boton que creo en el html este relacionado y haga lo que dice el metodo del archivo php

Tags: php, html

Estoy haciendo un juego tengo un dado y me da un nº del 0 al 9 segun el valor que de pues tengo unos premios. tengo  archivos el php y el html, entonce en el html tengo el boton jugar y quiero que la pulsar ese boton llame al metodo que he creado en php.
Me explico mejor. yo tengo un boton creado en el html un input type submint. Ese boton al pulsarlo quiero que llame al metodo   function partida() del PHP. Como hago eso?

```
<?php
        $costoPartida = 10;
        $creditos = 100;

        function partida() {
            $creditos -= 10;
            $resultado = math . random_int(0, 9);
            switch ($resultado) {
                case 2:
                    $creditos += 25;
                    $comentario = "ha salido: " + $resultado + "has ganado 25 creditos";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $creditos += 100;
                    $comentario =  "ha salido: " + $resultado + "has ganado 100 creditos";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    $creditos += 5;
                    $comentario =  "ha salido: " + $resultado + "has ganado 5 creditos";
                    break;
                default:
                    $comentario =  "ha salido: " + $resultado + "intentalo de nuevo";
                    break;
            }
            echo $comentario;
        }
        ?>
```

eso es mi php y esto lo que tengo el html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>5 magico </title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
    <from name="InferfazPartida" method="post" action="Partida.php">
        <p>Patida del 5 magico</p>
        <br/>
         Creditos:   <span id="vidas"><?php $creditos ?></span>
        <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="jugar"/>
    </from>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Viendo que tu HTML tiene PHP entiendo que ya has importado tu archivo PHP donde tienes la función por lo que podrías hacer que el método retorne el valor de comentario:

```
<?php
    $costoPartida = 10;
    $creditos = 100;

    function partida() {
        $creditos -= 10;
        $resultado = math . random_int(0, 9);
        switch ($resultado) {
            case 2:
                $creditos += 25;
                $comentario = "ha salido: " + $resultado + "has ganado 25 creditos";
                break;
            case 3:
                $creditos += 100;
                $comentario =  "ha salido: " + $resultado + "has ganado 100 creditos";
                break;
            case 5:
                $creditos += 5;
                $comentario =  "ha salido: " + $resultado + "has ganado 5 creditos";
                break;
            default:
                $comentario =  "ha salido: " + $resultado + "intentalo de nuevo";
                break;
        }
        return $comentario;
    }
?>
```

Después en el archivo donde tienes el HTML simplemente llamas a la función y la imprimes:

```
<?php echo partida(); ?>
```

**Edit:**

No me queda del todo claro si el problema es que no puedes mostrar php en un archivo HTML, si tu archivo es **.html** es normal, para trabajar con php en el archivo, éste debe tener extensión **.php**.

Comment: a ver el boton creado en el html deberia llamar a la funcion jugar partida pero no lo hace porque no se como hacer referencia a que realice eso

Comment: @unknow por un lado tu archivo html debe tener extensión .php para que puedas trabajar con php en el, tras esto, tendrás que almacenar el valor de $comentario en algún sitio que puedas acceder al recargar la página tras hacer el submit (por ejemplo en una variable de sesión https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.session.php ), tu archivo php modificaria esa variable y tu archivo .php que contiene el HTML, imprimiría esa variable, aunque hay varias, esta sería una forma de compartir variables entre diferentes páginas.

Comment: El archivo html no se ni que extension tiene, tendra la que le haya puesto neatbeans al crearlo :P lo mirare. ^Pero sigues sin resulverme el problema como sabe el sumit lo que tiene que hacer como hago para que haga referencia a la funcion que he creado?
Respecto de la variable $comentario no hay que almacenar el valor en nigun sitio porque no varia segun el case tiene un texto u otro pero cuando recargues sigue teniendo ese mismo valor

Comment: @unknow si tu archivo no es .php NO puedes trabajar con php en él, por eso es lo primero que deberías mirar. Aun cuando hagas esto, tu submit llama a Partida.php, lo que te hará navegar a ese archivo donde entiendo que no esta el html, por eso una solución sería la que te he dicho en el anterior comentario,  almacenar el resultado en una variable que puedas utilizar tras recargar y después vuelves a navegar al html donde imprimes esta variable.

Comment: el arhcivo es php lo tengo todo metido en un solo archivo php ya solucione esom, pero de todas maneras si yo le doy al submit no ejecuta la partida

Comment: No puedes hacerlo con el planteamiento que creo que lo estás pensando, tenrías que plantearlo un poco diferente ya que cada vez que haces un submit, la página recarga tu script se vuelve a ejecutar de nuevo tal cual lo tenias excepto que añades valores a la supergolbal $_POST en este caso, por eso al hacer el submit y recargar no ves cambios.

Comment: Lo unico que tiene que manterenerse son lo creditos partir de 100 la primera vez y continuar entrando en el swich y sumando si es necesario. Si cres que debo cambiar el planteaminto dime como

Comment: Podrías por un lado hacer que al hacer el submir tu php guarde (o modifique) en una variable de sesión el resultado y en tu HTML, donde quieras que se muestre el resultado hacer una validación para ver si existe esta variable de sesión ($_SESSION['resultado'] por ejemplo -  https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.session.php ) y de ser así imprimes su valor, en caso contrario imprimes algo como "Empieza a jugar", así tu submit va modificando los valores de esta variable, entre medio necesitarás varias validaciones para que funcione correctamente pero esta sería una manera de trabajar el problema.

Comment: uf eso es muy dificil yo acabo de empezar pero mi profesor no explica hay que aprebder por ciencia infusa

Answer (score 1):

Viendo que has separado la vista HTML del archivo PHP, podrias configurar el action del formulario para que mande a la misma ventana, tambien en el mismo archivo HTML incluir el archivo donde tienes la funcion partida, en caso dado de que al haber POST, se inicie el juego, de esta manera:

En el archivo HTML pones:

```
<?php
include('archivoPartida.php');

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
   partida();
}
?>
```

y en la etiqueta de formulario llamas al mismo archivo:

```
<form name="InferfazPartida" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']"; ?>>
```

Comment: entiedo que sustituyo el from de html por eso que me pones 1º pero lo 2º no se donde meterlo.
Y eso no me resuelve el problema de como hacer que el boton este referenciado con la funcion JugarPartida